# IMERG precipitation from mm/hr to mm/month using NCO

Tags: netcdf

I have IMERG monthly rainfall data with unit mm/hr, and in nc4 format. Downloaded from https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/GPM_3IMERGM_06/summary?keywords=IMERG

And I want to use the data to calculate SPI and required precipitation in mm/month. After reading various threads, NCO is the best software to do the conversion. The problem, I never used NCO before and was not familiar with it.

After reading the documentation, I found it could be done using ncap2 command but I am still confused with it.

Case: for a month with 31days, I need to multiply the data with 744 (24h*31day) so I can write the code

```
ncap2 -s 'precipitation=744*precipitation' in.nc4 out.nc4
```

And it's worked.

The problem, I have merged all the nc4 into a single nc4. How to apply the above code with that condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way but not really efficient, at least faster than manual one-by-one

I need to do a conversion process using `ncap2` (arithmatic operator for netCDF files) command by multiplying number of day in month with 24hour. Example:

- Rainfall value in Month: JAN, MAR, MAY, JUL, AUG, OCT, DEC which has 31 days will multiply with 744 to get mm/month
- Rainfall value in Month: APR, JUN, SEP, NOV which has 30 days will multiply with 720 to get mm/month
- Rainfall value in Month: FEB in a leap year which has 29 days will multiply with 696 to get mm/month
- Rainfall value in Month: FEB in a normal year which has 28 days will multiply with 672 to get mm/month

To do the calculation, I will use below script to help generate line of codes for converting value of each data from mm/hr to mm/month

```
while read -r _file; do
    file=$(basename -- "$_file")
    yearmonth=$(echo "$file" | sed -E 's/.*\.3IMERG\.([0-9]{6})[0-9]{2}-.*/\1/')
    mult=$(python - "$yearmonth" <<EOF
import sys, calendar
ym = sys.argv[1]
print(calendar.monthrange(int(ym[:4]), int(ym[4:]))[1] * 24)
EOF
);
    echo ncap2 -s 'precipitation='"$mult"'*precipitation' "$file" ../IMERG_mmmonth/"$file";
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.nc4") > script.sh
```

Paste above code in your Terminal and Enter. You will get a file named script.sh as the result.

Then execute in your terminal `sh script.sh`

You will get new files with `mm/month`, and ready to merge into single netcdf

Answer (score -1):

I followed the comment above but I got this error

```
ERROR: nco__create() unable to create file "../IMERG_mmmonth/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20121101-S000000-E235959.11.V06B.HDF5.SUB.nc4.pid33774.ncap2.tmp"
nco_err_exit(): ERROR Short NCO-generated message (usually name of function that triggered error): nco__create()
nco_err_exit(): ERROR Error code is 13. Translation into English with nc_strerror(13) is "Permission denied"
nco_err_exit(): ERROR NCO will now exit with system call exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
ERROR: nco__create() unable to create file "../IMERG_mmmonth/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20090801-S000000-E235959.08.V06B.HDF5.SUB.nc4.pid33775.ncap2.tmp"
nco_err_exit(): ERROR Short NCO-generated message (usually name of function that triggered error): nco__create()
nco_err_exit(): ERROR Error code is 13. Translation into English with nc_strerror(13) is "Permission denied"
nco_err_exit(): ERROR NCO will now exit with system call exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
```

What could I have possibly done wrong?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, you've asked a new Question in the space reserved for an Answer (we are *not* a discussion forum), so this will likely be deleted by automatic review. When you post a Question, please post a *complete* problem description, including the software in use, a description of the data, and sufficient details that we can determine how you encountered the error.